# Regex to remove everything between two characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

```
"<a href=\"/formentries/formfile/13978\" target=\"_blank\">dog-00.jpg|image/jpeg</a>  <a href='/FormEntries/Delete' class='btnDeleteAttachment'  data-form-entry-id='366793'  data-attachment-id='13978'> [remove]</a><br /><a href=\"/formentries/formfile/13979\" target=\"_blank\">dog-01.docx|application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document</a>  <a href='/FormEntries/Delete' class='btnDeleteAttachment'  data-form-entry-id='366793'  data-attachment-id='13979'> [remove]</a><br /><a href=\"/formentries/formfile/13980\" target=\"_blank\">dog-02.png|image/png</a>  <a href='/FormEntries/Delete' class='btnDeleteAttachment'  data-form-entry-id='366793'  data-attachment-id='13980'> [remove]</a>"
```

If you were to format that nicely, you'll see something like this:

```
<a href=\"/formentries/formfile/13978\" target=\"_blank\">dog-00.jpg|image/jpeg</a>
<a href='/FormEntries/Delete' class='btnDeleteAttachment'  data-form-entry-id='366793'  data-attachment-id='13978'> [remove]</a>
<br />

<a href=\"/formentries/formfile/13979\" target=\"_blank\">dog-01.docx|application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document</a>
<a href='/FormEntries/Delete' class='btnDeleteAttachment'  data-form-entry-id='366793'  data-attachment-id='13979'> [remove]</a>
<br />

<a href=\"/formentries/formfile/13980\" target=\"_blank\">dog-02.png|image/png</a>
<a href='/FormEntries/Delete' class='btnDeleteAttachment'  data-form-entry-id='366793'  data-attachment-id='13980'> [remove]</a>
```

So I have a bunch of anchor tags with breaks between them. In each anchor's text, I want to remove the pipe character and the file type:

> dog-00.jpg|image/jpeg

becomes

> dog-00.jpg

And the regex ought to work for all future file types too, for example:

> dog-01.docx|application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

becomes

> dog-01.docx

I still need the full anchors, so after removing the file type, the text becomes:

```
<a href=\"/formentries/formfile/13978\" target=\"_blank\">dog-00.jpg</a>
<a href='/FormEntries/Delete' class='btnDeleteAttachment'  data-form-entry-id='366793'  data-attachment-id='13978'> [remove]</a>
<br />

<a href=\"/formentries/formfile/13979\" target=\"_blank\">dog-01.docx</a>
<a href='/FormEntries/Delete' class='btnDeleteAttachment'  data-form-entry-id='366793'  data-attachment-id='13979'> [remove]</a>
<br />
```

I am not very good at Regex, but I tried various combinations that all failed to match

Comment: Is there a reason `text.Split("|")[0]` wouldn't work?

Comment: `input.Split('|')[0]` would be better, but Dylan Nicholson is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=<a[^>]*>[^|]+?)\|.*?(?=</a>)
```

For C#:

```
 your_string = Regex.Replace(your_string, "(?<=<a[^>]*>[^|]+?)\\|.*?(?=</a>)", "",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Just replace the string using this regex.

Comment: Updated the question. I do not just want the inside part of the anchor. I want to remove the pipe character and the file type, but leave everything else in the string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter -  regex approach is enough i think. This is one line solution.

Comment: @karthikselvaraj: one line that doesn't work always is not enough. Parsing dynamic html with regex is not very reliable. You know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/28424)?

Comment: @karthikselvaraj your code seems to only return 1 anchor instead of 6

Comment: @Ciwan - I have tested the code. please check - https://ideone.com/6GoqCt

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex to parse complex HTML, you can use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex). I'd also use string methods like `Contains`, `IndexOf` and `Remove` instead of regex:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html); // pass in your HTML string

foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    string text = link.InnerText;
    if (text.Contains('|'))
        link.InnerHtml = text.Remove(text.IndexOf('|')); // you can't modify InnerText directly but this works
}

string result = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml; // your desired result
```

Answer (score 0):

Input:
`dog-00.jpg|image/jpeg`

Regex that matches only the part before the `|` pipe:
`([^|]+)`

description:
The above regex matches everything until the first pipe-character occurs.

C# code:

```
var input = @"dog-00.jpg|image/jpeg";
var regex = new Regex(@"([^|]+)");
var m = regex.Match(input);
string name = null;
if (m.Success)
{
     name = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

EDIT:
If this is only about spliting the string by the pipe-character, Dylan Nicholson's variant with `input.Split` (or `.Substring` + `.IndexOf`) might be more performant that regular expressions...

EDIT2:
Are regular expressions required? If not, try the following:

```
public static string Clean(string input)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(input);
    int m1 = -1, m2 = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
    {
        if (sb[i] == '|')
            m1 = i;
        if (sb[i] == '<')
            m2 = i;
        if (m1 > -1 && m2 > -1 && m2 > m1)
        {
            sb.Remove(m1, m2 - m1);
            i = m1;
            m1 = -1;
            m2 = -1;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I've updated the question. I wish my string to remain the same (e.g. all the anchor tags ..etc), I only want the pipe and the file type that comes after that to be removed.

Comment: @Ciwan Updated my answer with a non-regex-variant that keeps the html code untouched...